# Why is my function just skipping over the code that uses HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

The first half of my function doesn't use htmlagilitypack and I know it functions as I want. however the function finishes without doing anything with the second half and doesnt return an errors. Please help

```
void classListHtml()
    {

        HtmlElementCollection elements = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("tr");
        html = "<table>";
        int i = 0;
        foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
        {
            if (element.InnerHtml.Contains("Marking Period 2") && i != 0)//will be changed to current assignment reports later
            {
                html += "" + element.OuterHtml;
            }
            else if (i == 0)
            {
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            else
                continue;

        }
        html += "" + "</table>";
        myDocumentText(html);


        //---------THIS IS WHERE IT STOPS DOING WHAT I WANT-----------
        //removing color and other attributes
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(html);
        HtmlNodeCollection nodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");//xpath expression for all row nodes
        string[] blackListAttributes={"width", "valign","bgcolor","align","class"};

        foreach(HtmlNode node in nodeCollection)//for each row node
        {
            HtmlAttributeCollection rows = node.Attributes;// the attributes of each row node

            foreach (HtmlAttribute attribute in rows)//for each attribute
            {
                if (blackListAttributes.Contains(attribute.Name))//if its attribute name is in the blacklist, remove it.
                    attribute.Remove();
            }
        }

        html = doc.ToString();
        myDocumentText(html);//updating browser with new html


    }
```

Comment: Sorry Iam off for now but; 1) Is it debug compiled? Both your project and htmlagilitypack? Otherwise it will seem to jump over the code when debugging. 2) Dont use black lists. Use white lists other wise you *will* be volnurable!

Comment: Also, make sure you use `StringBuilder`, not string concatenation (`+`) - a loop like this is the ideal scenario for `StringBuilder`

Comment: If you debug into it, do you get there? I wonder if `myDocumentText(html);` is doing something nasty - what happens if you remove the first call to `myDocumentText(html);`, just leaving the one at the end?

Answer (score 0):

`HtmlDocument.ToString()` does not send back the text, unless you changed the original code, maybe you're looking for `HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterXml` or `Document.Save( ... text ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
myDocumentText(html);
```

What does this method do?

My assumption is that you have an exception being thrown somewhere within this method, and it's either being swallowed, or your debug environment is set to not break on user thrown exceptions.

Can you post the code within this method?